# Creating Rectangle-based buttons with OnClick events

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, events

As the title implies, I want a Button class with an `OnClick` event handler. It should fire off connected events when it is clicked.

This is as far as I've made it:

```
public class Button {

    public event EventHandler OnClick;

    public Rectangle Rec { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public Button(Rectangle rec, string text) {
        this.Rec = rec;
        this.Text = text;
    }

}
```

I have no clue what I'm doing with regards to events. I know how to use them but creating them myself is another matter entirely. I've also made buttons without using events that work on a case-by-case basis.

So basically, I want to be able to attach methods to the `OnClick` EventHandler that will fire when the Button is clicked (i.e., the mouse intersects Rec and the left mouse button is clicked).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, you need to sample the state of the mouse regularly, and when it's clicked, check the coordinates against the button and see how that goes.

Usually, I write something like this in `Button`:

```
public void Update() { // called every tick
  var mouseState = Mouse.GetState();
  if (this.OnClick != null && mouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && oldState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released) {
    // Someone's listening, and we have a click
    this.OnClick.Invoke();
  }
  this.oldState = mouseState;
}
```

The core is really:

- Check the mouse state now
- Compare to the old state last tick. If we weren't pressed, and now we are, that's a click.
- Check if anyone's subscribing to our event (`this.OnClick != null`), and if so, notify them of the click.

By the way, your event can use `Action` if you pass no parameters to the subscribers of the click event (C# Forms defaults is to use sender and event args); `Action` can take parameters if you *do* want to send some data over.

Eg. you can make your event `public event Action OnClick`.

Comment: Wouldn't your code call the OnClick event no matter where the mouse is actually located when it's clicked? Unintentional mistake?

Comment: Yea, just add some Rectangle-point detection.

Comment: events do have parameters too. And it's better to register a delegate, than use a generic action. this way you have a well defined event

Comment: I intentionally wrote a simplistic example. I agree that using delegates gives better-defined events.

Comment: Thanks for this, had to adapt it a bit but it helped a lot. Also posted my adapted solution as a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

For those interested, this is my final (so far) Button class:

```
public class Button {

    public event Action OnClick;
    public event Action OnHover;

    public Rectangle Rec { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public Button(Rectangle rec, string text) {
        this.Rec = rec;
        this.Text = text;
    }

    public void Update(MouseState prev, MouseState cur) { // called every tick 
        if (this.OnClick != null && Rec.Contains(cur.X, cur.Y) && cur.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && prev.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released) { 
            // Someone's listening, and we have a click 
            this.OnClick.Invoke();
        }
        if (this.OnHover != null && Rec.Contains(cur.X, cur.Y)) {
            // Someone's listening, and we have a hover 
            this.OnHover.Invoke();
        }
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Color btnCol, Color textCol) {
        spriteBatch.Draw(Game1.TheGame.GuiTex, Rec, btnCol);
        Vector2 fontCenter = Game1.TheGame.DebugFont.MeasureString(Text) / 2;
        spriteBatch.DrawString(Game1.TheGame.DebugFont, Text, new Vector2(Rec.Center.X, Rec.Center.Y), textCol, 0, fontCenter, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
    }
}
```

And here is an example of how it is used:

```
Button[] menuOptions;
int selectedOption = 0;

...

menuOptions = new Button[3] {
    new Button(new Rectangle(x, y, width, height), "New Game"),
    new Button(new Rectangle(x, y, width, height), "Load Game"),
    new Button(new Rectangle(x, y, width, height), "Settings")
};

...

for (int i = 0; i < menuOptions.Length; i++) {
    int j = i; // this is due to the way C# deals with closures and captured variables
    menuOptions[i].OnHover += delegate() { selectedOption = j; };
    menuOptions[i].OnClick += selectOption;
}

...

public void Draw(GameTime gameTime, SpriteBatch spriteBatch) {
    spriteBatch.Begin();
    foreach (Button btn in menuOptions) {
        Color btnCol = (btn == menuOptions[selectedOption]) ? Color.DarkBlue : Color.CadetBlue;
        Color textCol = (btn == menuOptions[selectedOption]) ? Color.White : Color.Black;
        btn.Draw(spriteBatch, btnCol, textCol);
    }
    spriteBatch.End();
}

...

private void selectOption() {
    if (selectedOption == 0) { // New Game
        // do new game stuff
    } else if (selectedOption == 1) { // Load Game
        // do load game stuff
    } else if (selectedOption == 2) { // Settings
        // do settings stuff
    }
}
```

This example is far from perfect and it would have to be adapted to any specific needs, but it should help.

Comment: +1, I didn't know you can use `Rec.Contains`. That's quite awesome

Comment: sorry, i'm new to the platform.... how is Update in the Button class invoked on every click? How do you wire it?

Answer (score 0):

The [button WinForms control](http://www.kettic.com/winforms_ui/buttons_overview.shtml) is able to add themes, rotation and transparency, images and text to C#.NET projects as well as creating rectangle buttons.